# Email not sending during development Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2.3

I want to send email templates to client. So during development I want to test it. I am doing following:

```
//app/config.yml

swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

And overwriting the details in app/config_dev.php as:

swiftmailer:
   transport:smtp
    host:      smtp.live.com
    username:  connect@live.com
    password:  test123
    spool:     { type: memory }
    disable_delivery:  false
    delivery_address: ssr@example.com
```

But email are not set-out to this : ssr@example.com address. Can anybody guide please what are else configuration need to do to send emails using smtp as transport.